# Synchronized collection

Tags: java, loops, synchronized

Since c is already synchronzied collection, and it's thus thread safe. But why do we have to use `synchronized(c)` again for the iteration? Really confused. Thanks.

" It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
collection when iterating over it:

```
Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);
 ...
 synchronized(c) {
     Iterator i = c.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
     while (i.hasNext()) {
         foo(i.next());
     }
}
```

Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior. "
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.

Answer (score 12):

The most any `synchronized` collection implementation could possibly do is to guarantee that each *individual method call* is synchronized.  But iteration necessarily involves multiple separate method calls, so you, the user of the synchronized collection, have to synchronize on the whole iteration yourself.

For example, if you didn't synchronize on `c`, the contents of the collection could change between `i.hasNext()` and `i.next()` -- it could even go from having elements to having no more elements, in which case `i.next()` would fail.

Comment: What do you mean by "necessarily involves multiple separate method calls"?

Comment: @user697911: `i.hasNext()` and `i.next()` are two separate method calls, and there's no possible way for the implementation of `Collections.synchronizedCollection` to ensure that nothing changes in between `i.hasNext()` and `i.next()`.

Comment: So, concurrentHashmap would be the same? Do we also have to synchronize the concurrenthashamp in iteration?

Comment: No, you never need to synchronize `ConcurrentHashMap`.  The docs for CHM state: "The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction."  In other words, `ConcurrentHashMap` uses a specialized implementation that makes sure its iterators don't blow up when you modify the map during iteration, and those iterators may or may not take into account further modifications.

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` can do things like that because concurrency is built in from the ground up; `Collections.synchronizedCollection` can only provide a simple wrapper around a not-normally-concurrent collection.

Answer (score 7):

Making all the methods on a class individually synchronized doesn't make an aggregation ( calling them in a group ) of those methods thread safe. By wrapping the `Iterator` in a synchronized block you are protecting that particular instance of the iterator from having its individual method called interspersed with other calls by multiple threads.

If I call `.add()` once it is safe, if I need to call `.add()` multiple times to complete a logical statement, there is no guarantee that someone else hasn't added something else or removed something else between my `.add()` calls unless I block everything else from calling `.add()` ( or any other method ) by `synchronizing` on the variable that represents the collection.

The `Iterator` makes mutiple calls to the individual methods on the collection, they all have to be wrapped in a single `synchronized` block to make them execute as a single `transaction` of sorts. Examine the source code of the implemenation of  `Iterator` you will see what I mean. Here is the source code for `List` it makes multiple individual calls to the underlying implementation, so they all need to be executed in uninterrupted order by the same thread to be deterministic.

```
  @Override
    public Iterator<A> iterator() {
        if (tail == null)
            return emptyIterator();
    return new Iterator<A>() {
        List<A> elems = List.this;
        public boolean hasNext() {
        return elems.tail != null;
        }
        public A next() {
                if (elems.tail == null)
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
        A result = elems.head;
        elems = elems.tail;
        return result;
        }
        public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };
    }
```

The [source](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/AbstractList.java.html) for `AbstractList.iterator()` shows even more complicated logic that makes multiple calls.

A better wrapper is wrapping them in `Immutable` collections, then you guarantee that nothing else can alter the underlying collection between calls.

Comment: best explanation I have come across!